# How to prevent Button enable or disable from view source

Tags: html, asp.net

I have two button on page first submit and other save but one there is one condition if admin log in Save button shows and if client log in submit button show. But bug is any one who log in can easily change disable to enable or enable to disable from view source and click the button

```
@{
  if((Utility.GetUserRoleFromSession().ToString().ToLower().Equals(UserRole.Client.ToString().ToLower())
  {
    <input type="button" value="Submit" title="submit" class="blueBtn" id="btnSubmit" />
  }
  if (Utility.GetUserRoleFromSession().ToLower().Equals(UserRole.Admin.ToString().ToLower())
  {
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnSubmitEE" class="btnSubmitEE blueBtn" />
  }
}
```

Comment: disable to enable or enable to disable from view source and click the button ? can you show me more example ?

Comment: Rolled back to r5 of question. Plain text code is preferred over screenshots of text.

Answer (score 0):

Make the button visible = false according to user. If button is invisible, then it will not appear in the viewsource.

Answer (score 0):

Make the button invisible to ensure that the button is not emitted to the rendered HTML.

As a second line of defense, put logic into the code-behind to verify that the user should be able to click the button before actually performing the logic on the server-side. This is analogous to performing both client-side validation and server-side validation, because the user can turn off JavaScript on the client-side, at that point server-side validation is all that is executed.

---

> Note: Bottom line is the server-side should NEVER trust anything the client provides to it.